# Как обойти warning C4996: std::transform::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate

Tags: c++, stl

```
const char* BuildPath( const char* base, const char* game, const char* relativePath ) {
    static char szPath[260];

    std::fill( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), 0 );
    // Махинации с путями
    sprintf_s( szPath, _countof( szPath ), "%s/%s/%s", base, game, relativePath );

    std::replace( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), '\\', '/' );
    std::transform( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), std::begin( szPath ),
                    [] ( unsigned char c ) { return ::tolower( c ); } ); //4996
    return szPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `array`:

```
const char* BuildPath( const char* base, const char* game, const char* relativePath ) {
    static ::std::array<char, 260> szPath;

    std::fill( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), 0 );
    // Махинации с путями
    sprintf_s(szPath.data(), szPath.size(), "%s/%s/%s", base, game, relativePath );

    std::replace( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), '\\', '/' );
    std::transform( std::begin( szPath ), std::end( szPath ), std::begin( szPath ),
                    [] ( unsigned char c ) { return ::tolower( c ); } ); //4996
    return szPath.data();
}
```

Comment: Можно оставить и массив

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* BuildPath( const char* base, const char* game, const char* relativePath ) {
    static char szPath[260];
    std::fill(szPath ,  szPath  + 260, 0 );
    // Махинации с путями
    sprintf_s( szPath, _countof( szPath ), "%s/%s/%s", base, game, relativePath );

    std::replace(szPath , szPath + 260 , '\\', '/' );
    std::transform( szPath,  szPath + 260, szPath,
                    [] ( unsigned char c ) { return ::tolower( c ); } ); //4996
    return szPath;
}
```